# Which Cocoa class method formats [NSDate date] data into a sortable sequence key text string?

Tags: date, cocoa, format

I needed a date stamp that would be suitable for inclusion in a sequence key to be an argument for sorting a text file of dated records. I studied the Apple documentation and searched the internet and couldn't find a reference that actually met my criteria: a string formatted as

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS GMT

with the hours expressed in 24-hour (military) format. So I had to code my own date stamp formatting method as shown.

Inline comments helped at breakpoints in debugging the intricate C code, used for its low overhead. These comments include the `datetime` string produced by `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]`, and a representation of the development of the desired date stamp format. The comments with the caret `^` point to the current position of the scanning index.

```
NSMutableString * sortableMilitaryDateTimeStamp()
{
    NSString * datetime;
    NSDate   * date;
    NSMutableString * sortableDate;
    int  d, sln, s, hr, x;
    char c;
    char inpbuffer[24]; char * src = (char *) &inpbuffer;
    char dstbuffer[] = "....-..-.. ..:..:.. ...";
    char * dst = (char *) &dstbuffer;

    date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    datetime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    sfrsTMC(src,datetime.UTF8String,24); //copies datetime text to the C string

// "June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT"  to become  "2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT"
//  ^
// "....-..-.....:..:......"
    sln = strlen(src);
    d = 0;
    for (s = 0; (s <= sln) && (src[s] != ' '); s++) ;
    c = src[0];
    dst[5] = '0';
    x = src[2];
    switch (c) {
    case 'J':
        if (src[1] == 'a') dst[6] = '1';
        else
        if (x == 'l') dst[6] = '7';
        else
        if (x == 'n') dst[6] = '6';
        break;
    case 'F':
        src[6] = '2';
        break;
    case 'M':
        if (x == 'r') dst[6] = '3';
        else
        if (x == 'y') dst[6] = '5';
        break;
    case 'A':
        if (src[1] == 'p') dst[6] = '4';
        else
        if (src[1] == 'u') dst[6] = '8';
        break;
    case 'S':
       dst[6] = '9';
        break;
    case 'O':
        dst[6] = '1'; dst[6] = '0';
        break;
    case 'N':
         dst[6] = '1'; dst[6] = '1';
        break;
    case 'D':
        dst[6] = '1'; dst[6] = '2';
        break;
    }
// June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT  to  2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT
//     ^
// "....-06-.. ..:..:.. ..."
    if (src[s+2] = ',') {
        dst[8] = '0';
        dst[9] = src[++s]; }
    else {
        dst[8] = src[++s];
        dst[9] = src[++s];
    }
    s += 3;
// June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT  to  2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT
//         ^
// "....-06-02 ..:..:.. ..."
    d = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) dst[d++] = src[s++];
    s += 4;
// June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT  to  2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT
//                 ^
// "2018-06-02 ..:..:.. ..."
    if (src[s+1] == ':') {
        dst[11] = '0';
        hr = src[s] - '0';
        dst[12] = src[s++]; }
    else {
        hr = src[s] - '0';
        dst[11] = src[s++];
        hr = (hr * 10) + src[s] - '0';
        dst[12] = src[s++];
    }
// "2018-06-02 03:..:.. ..."
// June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT  to  2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT
//                  ^
    d = 13;
    for (x = 0; x < 7; x++) dst[d++] = src[s++];
// "2018-06-02 03:04:46 ..."
// June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT  to  2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT
//                         ^
    if (src[s] == 'P') {
        hr += 12;
        dst[11] = (int) (hr / 10) + '0';
        dst[12] = (hr % 10) + '0';
    }
    s += 3;
// "2018-06-02 15:04:46 ..."
// June 2, 2018 at 3:04:46 PM GMT  to  2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT
//                            ^
    d = 20;
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) dst[d++] = src[s++];
// "2018-06-02 15:04:46 GMT"

    sortableDate = @(dst).mutableCopy;
    return sortableDate;
}
```

Believe it or not, this works. However I can't help thinking I've done something stupid by failing to find a method supported by some native Cocoa class method. I suspect there must be something that could convert the `[NSDate date]` information directly.

Please, how could I do something more appropriate? Any constructive criticism will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `setDateFormat:` to set the date format of the formatter instead of `setDateStyle:` and `setTimeStyle:`.

Comment: I think I rejected that somewhere along the line for some reason, but I will revisit it with greater attention now. Thanks.

Comment: @Willeke My hero. I'll put the result of your suggestion into the Answer Your Question area below. Perhaps it will save someone else some time and needless work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the requirements for invoking the formatting procedure:

```
NSMutableString * sortableDate;
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
sortableDate = makeSortableDateTimeStamp(date);
```

And here's the formatting procedure:

```
NSMutableString * makeSortableDateTimeStamp (NSDate * date)
{
    NSMutableString * datetime;
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'zzz"];
    datetime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date].mutableCopy;
    return datetime;
}
```

The coding for the `setDataFormat:` string is specified in:

> http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

There are several similar unicode.org/reports covering various versions of development. I chose this one because it was indicated for use with my version of macOS and Xcode.

Thanks again to Willeke for such generous and astute advice.

Comment: @Willeke Is this what you were suggesting? It works perfectly. Thank you.